# CodeIgniter 3: Submit to Controller in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a notification feature and I wanted the ajax to be able to run a query via the controller on button click

**THIS IS MY SCRIPT**

```
 $('#noti_Button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url("profile/read_notif")?>'

            });
});
```

**THE CONTROLLER**

```
public function read_notif(){
        $this->profile_model->read_notifs($data['id']);
        return;
    }
```

**AND THE MODEL**

```
 function read_notifs($id)
    {
        $read = array(
        'read' => '1'
        );
        $this->db->where('recipient', $id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_notifications', $read);
        return;
    }
```

I tried this and the data in the database doesn't update. 
**IN MY HTML IT IS JUST A SIMPLE BUTTON**

Comment: AJAX is missing with `id` (data)

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I was just getting my data['id'] from my session() function in controller

Comment: a `});` is missing in the last portion of your script.

Comment: oww I just missed to copy it form my text file. sorry @HananAshraf

Comment: ok.. so your click is working? before going to ajax call, just check if click action is working.

Comment: @HananAshraf i checked the click and it's working. Do I still have to add something inside `$.ajax({});` ?

Comment: just return your last performed query to the success part of your ajax call.

Comment: @HananAshraf i should add this exact code `success: function (data) {  
                alert("Ajax success");
               }`??

Comment: not really. `alert(data)` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script

```
$('#noti_Button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url("profile/read_notif")?>',
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }

        });
    });
```

Controller

```
public function read_notif(){
        $this->profile_model->read_notifs($data['id']);
        echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**It is the sample calling the ajax in ruby on rails . In this code we are calling the controller for getting the values.**

```
$('#Button').on('change', function(event) {
  var selected_resource_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({ 
   type: 'GET', 
   url: "<%= Home_index_path %>",
   data: { id: selected_resource_id }, 
   success: function (data) {  
    alert("Ajax success");
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use error: to check if there's any error in submitting your form.

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url("profile/read_notif")?>',
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }

        });
    });
```